# Can I make a class unsealed internally but sealed externally?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

In C# is it possible to make a class that can be derived from internally (unsealed), but then prevent other people referencing my library externally from inheriting from my public class (sealed)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suppose you could make the constructor of the class `internal` so that only other classes in your assembly could derive from them, if you still need to create instances of that class you could provide a factory method to return instances.

edit to add a sample:

```
public class MyFoo
{
    internal MyFoo()
    {
    }

    public static MyFoo CreateFoo()
    {
        return new MyFoo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Eric Lippert notes three ways to do this.  tl;dr: don't seal your class, but include an internal abstract method in your class, or make all the constructors internal or private, or use the [`PermissionSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.permissionset?view=net-6.0) attribute to add metadata to the class.

- https://web.archive.org/web/20150905101050/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/26/preventing-third-party-derivation-part-one.aspx
- https://web.archive.org/web/20151029232826/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/10/06/preventing-third-party-derivation-part-two.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can also try doing something like this.

```
internal class InternalExtendible
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public sealed class ExternalSealedClass : InternalExtendible
{
}
```

Create an Internal class and create a public empty class that inherits from the internal class. When referencing the dll, only the public class will be visible to the user, but all the functionality of the internal class will be exposed.

Comment: Occurred to me, but the big problem is that if there are public accessible methods consuming or returning this type -- what is the signature?  If you use `ExternalSealedClass`, your "real" inheritors won't be eligible.  If you use `InternalExtensible`, your methods can't be public anymore.

Comment: @mquander Couldn't you just get around that by programming to an interface? i.e. your signature would look like "void DoSomething(IExtendableOrSealed item) { ... }"